# Excel - selecting range until 5 empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

On a spreadsheet that works as an order form, the data begins on row 84. From there, there can be as few as 1 row of data or as many as thousands. Also, sometimes there will be blank rows within that data.

I have many instances of statements like this in my VBA codes:

```
Range("A84:X1000").Select
```

The problem is that sometimes that range goes much lower than it needs to be, and other times it's not far enough. Is there a way to make a range start in a specific cell (A84 in this case) and end only after it reaches 5 blank rows?

To give an example of when I need to use it, here's one bit of VBA code.

```
Sub FixNumbers()
Range("D84:D1000").Select
Dim c As Range

Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
For Each c In Selection.Cells
  If (c > 99) And (c Mod 50) = 0 Then c = c + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: why not this : range(range("A84"), cells(activesheet.usedrange.rows.count,1)) ?

Comment: @Pierre I added an example of how I'm currently using the Range. How would I implement that into what I have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking previous answerer's idea:

```
Sub FixNumbers()
with Range("D84:D" & rows.count)
    Dim c As Range
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    For Each c In .Cells
        If (c > 99) And (c Mod 50) = 0 Then c = c + 1
    Next
end with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the xlUp method?  This simulates you selecting bottom row and pressing ctrl + up:

```
Set rngOppos = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X84", Sheets("sheet1").Range("X" & rows.count).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: Actually, ".Range("X" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row +5) would do it.

Comment: I added an example of how I'm currently using the Range. How would I implement that into what I have now?